# Rails - saving a regex string to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm trying to save a regex string from a form in my Rails 5 app (Postgresql database), but I'm having issues with it escaping strings.

For example, if I try to save this in my form - "test(\'s)?" it will only save as "test(\\'s)?".

I can see that when it's passed as a parameter is when the extra slash is being added and I believe adding `html_safe` would fix it, but I'm using a gem that I don't think would allow this.

`<%= best_in_place @test, :find_regex, place_holder: "empty" %>`

Is there a reliable way I can modify the parameters after they are passed for this one attribute so it doesn't escape single slashes?

Comment: What do you mean by `regex string` in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

To preserve the string try to encode it to base64 then store it to the database.